# Firefox Internal Error: too much recursion

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting the error `Internal Error: too much recursion` from Firefox. I am trying to make an ajax call using jquery. With Internet Explorer it is working fine.

I am not calling any function recursively.

Please give me some suggestion. Thanks

```
 $(function(){
      $('#delivery').accordion({
           header: '.accTrigger',
           autoHeight: false,
           animated: 'easeslide',
           change: function(event, ui) {
                alert("here");
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                     url: URL,
                     type: 'GET',
                     dataType: 'html',
                     timeout: 18000,
                     success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                          alert("sus");
                     },
                     error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                          alert("err" + errorThrown);
                     }
                });     

                $("input",ui.newHeader).prop("checked","checked");
                $("input",ui.newHeader).trigger('click');

                $(".accSection").each(function() {
                     $(this).removeClass("active");
                });

                ui.newHeader.parent().addClass("active");
                fitContentBackground();
           }
      });

      /**
      * Loop through all the payment types and enable the respective accordin
      */
      $.each($('.accSection'), function(index, value) {
           if ($('input[type="radio"]', value).is(':checked') == true) {
                $('#delivery').accordion('activate',index);
                $(this).addClass("active");
           } 
           else {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
           }
      });
 });
```

Thanks all for the response

I am sorry for adding entire code, it triggered so much of confusion..

Even this simple snippet also generating the same error (InternalError: too much recursion)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#buttontest123").click(function(evt){
  alert("herepavan");
  evt.preventDefault();

  setPayment();




});

function setPayment()
{   
      alert("here1");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'URL',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',

        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

           alert("sus");
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert("err"+errorThrown);
        }
    });


}

});

</script>
```

Comment: I'm only speculating here, since I don't know what plugin you are using... You have a change callback, that I guess is triggered whenever the accordion changes. Within that callback you change stuff (adding/removing classes etc). Could it be that they are considered changes, triggering the change-callback again - throwing you into an infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not getting any error without ajax script. That too error is from the error function.

Answer (score 3):

I think triggering click event for an element in the newHeader element will cause a change event (which will be recusive)

```
 $("input",ui.newHeader).trigger('click');
```

try to replace the above line by any other logic (do not trigger 'click', just call the code you want)

Comment: Hi MhdSyrwan, As i updated with recent snippet which is not having any click events, but still it is throwing the same exception.. kindly let me know your further inputs

Comment: i've tested your new snippet .. it's working without throwing any exception!